# Reg. Webmethods Integration server DocumentStore

Tags: webmethods

In our webmethods server DocumentStore, too many TriggerStoredata files(TriggerStoredata0000000 to TriggerStoredata0000092) are getting created. They take up lot of disk space too. What is the reason for this and can these files be deleted? What is the impact ? Appreciate your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The files in this subdirectory contain the locally persisted documents being processed
by Integration Server. The loss of these files will result in the loss of any persisted
documents.

Since these are related to Triggers, please verify your subscription service, it maybe trowing errors or stuckup somewhere.

For more information on subdirectories refer: http://www.idnxchange.com/webmethods-blogs/subdirectories-in-webmethods-integration-servers.html